# Apache Flink example job fails to run with "Job not found"

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Attempting to run the SocketWindowWordCount example tutorial found on the flink site [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/tutorials/local_setup.html).

I started the flink cluster, then ran a local socket server:

```
nc -l 9000
```

After compiling the example source taken from [github](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.8.0/flink-examples/flink-examples-streaming/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/examples/socket/SocketWindowWordCount.java), I run the job

```
flink run target/SocketWindowWordCount.jar  --port 9000
```

I then input some words to the terminal running `nc`.  Nothing goes to the expected output file and the log has this error repeating:

```
2019-07-09 15:54:32,673 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.job.JobDetailsHandler   - Exception occurred in REST handler: Job f9b3c58ca3026855fd2612e3c86551fa not found
2019-07-09 15:54:35,673 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.job.JobDetailsHandler   - Exception occurred in REST handler: Job f9b3c58ca3026855fd2612e3c86551fa not found
2019-07-09 15:54:38,673 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.job.JobDetailsHandler   - Exception occurred in REST handler: Job f9b3c58ca3026855fd2612e3c86551fa not found
2019-07-09 15:54:39,769 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.job.JobDetailsHandler   - Exception occurred in REST handler: Job f9b3c58ca3026855fd2612e3c86551fa not found
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is usually happening when you have a Flink UI tab open in your browser, which is left open from previous job deployments.
So the UI is pointing to a URL with http://.../f9b3c58ca3026855fd2612e3c86551fa which is a JobID that doesn't exist. This causes the above log to show up.